# Pandas group by using values in a Column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to group the values in my DataFrame by a separation value such that everything in between is grouped together. In my case I would like `Status == Finished` to separate the grouping. I am not sure how to do this with pandas, Example:

I have a data frame as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status':['Pending', 'Pending', 'Finished', 'Finished', 'Pending', 'Finished'], "Value":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

     Status  Value
0   Pending      1
1   Pending      2
2  Finished      3
3  Finished      4
4   Pending      5
5  Finished      6
```

I would like to this to become 3 Separate DataFrames:

```
     Status  Value
0   Pending      1
1   Pending      2
2  Finished      3

     Status  Value
3  Finished      4

     Status  Value
4   Pending      5
5  Finished      6
```

Comment: Why isn't the last finished a separated group?

Comment: I want to include all the rows before the separator @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.Status.eq('Finished').iloc[::-1].cumsum())))
d[1]
Out[229]: 
     Status  Value
4   Pending      5
5  Finished      6
d[2]
Out[230]: 
     Status  Value
3  Finished      4
```

Comment: This is great! Strange how the ordering changes not sure how to fix that but I can safely go from `len(d)` to 1 I'm assuming?

Comment: @pyCthon order change due to I cumsum the value bottom up , .iloc[::-1]